# Get digits of an input number and store them in array in the same order java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a program, where I enter a number, for example 12345, and I want to store each digit into array, in that exact order.

Right now I'm doing it like this, but I was wondering if there is a better way:

```
 int[] array = createArray(12345678);

 public static int[] createArray(int a) {
    int[] array = new int[countDigits(a)];
    int i = 0;

    while (a != 0) {
        int b = a % 10;
        array[i] = b;
        a = a / 10;
        i++;
    }

    return reverseArray(array);
}

public static int[] reverseArray(int[] array) {
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
    int j = array.length - 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = array[j];
        j--;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

If I don't use the reverseArray method, the digits in the array are going to be 8, 7, 6... Is there a way to add those digits in 1, 2, 3... order without the reverseArray method?

I could also conver it to string and use the charAt[], but I think sometimes it can store a wrong number, if instead of a number 1 it adds the ASCII representation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your version of `countDigits`, but in decimal the relationship between the number of digits, the current digit and the initial value is controlled by *logarithm 10*. Thus, you can use `Math.log` to determine the number of digits and the inverse operation of exponentiation to find the digits left to right. Like,

```
public static int[] createArray(int a) {
    int len = 1 + (int) (Math.log(a) / Math.log(10));
    int[] array = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int pow10 = (int) Math.pow(10, len - i - 1);
        int digit = a / pow10;
        array[i] = digit;
        a -= digit * pow10;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to include it:

public static int countDigits(int a) {
        String counter = "" + a;
        return counter.length();
    }

I'm not used to using Math functions, but I get what you did here, and your way of solving it is very clever! And it works great, even if the input number is negative. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the integer to a `String` with `String.valueOf`, get a stream of characters (converted to `int`) with `String#chars`, then `map` the stream with `Character.getNumericValue` to get the actual digit corresponding to each character, and finally create an array with `.toArray()`.

```java
public static int[] createArray(int a) {
    return String.valueOf(a).chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm at the basics of Java and still haven't covered streams, but I could follow your logic and I really like this solution. Thanks!

Comment: When I tried this approach if I place -2345, the output is -1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Is there a way to solve this case?

Comment: @Lenzz920 Just take the absolute value if you don't want the negative sign: `String.valueOf(Math.abs(a))`. What is the expected result though?

Answer (score 0):

Without using the reverseArray method, you can change createArray as follows:

```
   public static int[] createArray(int a) {
    int[] array = new int[countDigits(a)];
    int i = array.length - 1;

    while (a != 0) {
        int b = a % 10;
        array[i] = b;
        a = a / 10;
        i--;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: That's a very good approach, replacing the whole method with just saving the numbers in the array from the end -> start. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the integer to a *String*, and then iterate on each character.

The *[Character#digit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,int))* method will return a corresponding *int* value, given a specified *char* and radix.

```java
int integer = 12345;
String string = String.valueOf(integer);
int[] array = new int[string.length()];
for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
    array[index] = Character.digit(string.charAt(index), 10);
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: So in this way it's converting the charAt(index) directly to the int value. I was worried that if I use the charAt, it could save the ASCII # instead of the actual number. But that seems to work fine, thanks!

Comment: @Lenzz920, the _digit_ method will take an ASCII code, or character, as the parameter, and return the actual value, given the _radix_.  For example, _Character.digit('a', 16)_ will return _10_, since _a_ is 10, in hexadecimal.  Glad it helped, no problem.